# What is the right definition of tick?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw different definitions of "tick" in javascript and node.js event loop.

- Some say it's the 1 iteration that passes throughout all the phases
  of the event loop.
- Some say that the transition between a phase and
  another is a tick.
- Some say it's dequeuing of an event(or all the
  events) from the "event loop queue", where I understand that node's
  event loop has a queue for each phase, not just one queue. (in
  addition to the other queues "micro tasks queue" and "next tick
  queue")

So that makes me confused on the definition of "tick" and what exactly it is, and how many queues there are.

Comment: As far as I know this is a very complicated topic, maybe [this guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick) can help you.

Comment: tick is just a word. has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

A tick, according to the [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) is best described in [this paragraph](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick-vs-setimmediate)

> ### process.nextTick() vs setImmediate()
>
> We have two calls that are similar as far as users are concerned, but their names are confusing.
>
> - `process.nextTick()` fires immediately on the same phase
> - `setImmediate()` fires on the following iteration or ***'tick'*** of the event loop
>
> In essence, the names should be swapped. `process.nextTick()` fires more immediately than `setImmediate()`, but this is an artifact of the past which is unlikely to change. Making this switch would break a large percentage of the packages on npm. Every day more new modules are being added, which means every day we wait, more potential breakages occur. While they are confusing, the names themselves won't change.

So, to me, this reads as NodeJS having defined a tick to mean one pass through all [7 phases](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#phases-overview) of the event loop.

Honestly, though, it's probably not worth arguing over. If you're having a debate with someone, you can show them this doc, but if they remain unconvinced, move on, it's just a word.

Comment: You are right, what just doesn't make sense is that process.nextTick means (before next phase) not (before the next whole iteration after all phases of current iteration).

Comment: @YoussefMohamed - yes. They specifically acknowledge the fact that the naming is poor and results in confusion.

Comment: But there is something else important, it says up here setImmediate fires on the following iteration(tick), while we know that setImmediate fires on the following phase after the poll phase not next iteration.. so does this mean that iteration of a loop here means 1 phase ?

Comment: @YoussefMohamed - there are [7 phases](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#phases-overview) to the event loop. callbacks schedules with `setImmediate` fire in the `check` phase. It sounds like, no matter which phase you are at in the event loop, if you schedule a callback with `setImmediate` it waits until the `check` phase on the next iteration of the event loop before executing your callback.